# How to close hover dropdown menu on outside click?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu

I really do not want to lose the hover capability, I need a way without losing the hover capability.

In pure CSS (no JavaScript), how do I get the dropdown menu to close on clicks outside of the dropdown menu, without losing the hover capability?

Here is an example of someone who did a JavaScript dropdown menu with the feature of closing on outside clicks.

https://koen.kivits.com/articles/pure-css-menu/

Here is my dropdown menu CSS with hover and onClick:

```
  .acn-menu {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}

.label_openclose {
  display: none;
}

.menu-tabs {
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

/* This CSS makes the Solutions dropdown menu push
   down the other two items when in mobile view. */
@media (min-width: 320px) {
  .menu-tabs {
  position: absolute;
  }
}

.menu-tabs .elem {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 20px;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 70px;
  background-color: rgb(30, 30, 30);
  color: white;
}

.menu-check {
  display: none;
}


label {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.label_openclose {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  min-height: 50px;
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:block;
}

.menu-tabs .elem {
  line-height: initial;
  float: initial;
  height: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-top: 0px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu-check:checked~.menu-tabs .elem {
  height: 25px;
  color: white;
  border-top: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

.label_openclose:hover~.menu-tabs .elem {
  border-top: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  height: 25px;
}
 .label_openclose~.menu-tabs:hover .elem {
  border-top: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  height: 25px;
}
```

Is it possible for me to get the close-on-click without using JS? Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Ld5L2tnf/

Comment: I've removed the request for free work from your post - please always write your question with the assumption that people are willing to help, but do not wish to be sources of free labour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reviewed your code and posted an example of what you want.  This is a more simple way of achieving your goal. This is an example you will have to apply it to your code. This is a pure css and html solution using checkboxes and labels. Below is detailed information on how it works. Hope it helps. Enjoy.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
.buttoncomtainer1{ /*A wrapper for your hover dropdown List*/
width:100px;
height:2em;
float:left;
position:absolute;  
z-index:20;
}
.mycheckButton{ /*Your Label acts as a Button Triggering the checkbox*/
width:100px;
height:2em;
float:left;
display:block;
background-color:blue;
text-align:center;
color:#ffffff;
position:fixed; 
z-index:20;
}
.mycheckDrop{ /*Your Dropdown*/
width:100px;
float:left;
display:none;
padding:1%;
background-color:green;
position:fixed; 
z-index:20;
margin-top:2em;
}

.gone{ /*Make your checkbox disappear*/
border:0px;
outline:none;
line-height:0;
display:none;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
width:0px;
height:0px;
}
.blackout{ /*This Div covers the page with the labelBlackout Label in it. nothing can be clicked unless The Label inside clicked first triggering the checkbox. */
width:100%;
height:100%;
float:left;
position:fixed;
z-index:15; 
background-color:transparent; /*    You can add a background color like this. background-color:black; opacity:0.7;*/
display:none;
}  
.labelBlackout{ /*the Label inside the blackout div that covers the page*/
width:100%;
height:100%;
float:left; 
}  
.lnkCon{    /*  Container that holds your dropdown links.*/
width:100%;
height:2em;
float:left; 
margin-top:5px;
}
input[type=checkbox].gone:checked ~ div.blackout{display:block;}  
input[type=checkbox].gone:checked ~ label.mycheckDrop{display:block;}    
.buttoncomtainer1:hover > .mycheckDrop{display:block;}


</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="buttoncomtainer1">
<input class="gone" id="myCheck" type="checkbox" >
<div class="blackout" ><label class="labelBlackout" for="myCheck"></label></div>
<label class="mycheckButton" for="myCheck">DropDown</label>
<label class="mycheckDrop" for="myCheck">
<span class="lnkCon"><a href="#">Button 1</a></span>
<span class="lnkCon"><a href="#">Button 2</a></span>
<span class="lnkCon"><a href="#">button 3</a></span>
</label></div>
</body>
</html>
```